# where and how activiti model diagram is being stored in the activiti database tables

Tags: workflow, alfresco, activiti, bpmn

I have started working on activiti i wanted to know after creating/editing process model where and how activiti model diagram is being stored in the activiti database tablel ?

Also  When we edit an activiti model, the version remains as version 1 is there any way to increment this version and how multiple versions can be tracked in the activiti database?
i can see version are incremented when there is duplicate deployment. but how to increment version after edit model
[image]
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Which version of Activiti are you using?

Comment: I am having activiti 5.15.1 version.

Answer (score 2):

Please check out the "3.7. Database table names explained" and "5.4. Automatic resource deployment" sections of the user guide (https://www.activiti.org/userguide/)

You may also list table information and data: https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#_database_tables

Comment: Thanks for response @Curtis , i also wanted to know that after editing any workflow can we increment the version ? for example initially it is version 1 , so after editing model can we change it to version 2, version 3 ...version n ?

Comment: There is a version tag you may increment:  <bpmn2:process id="process-5f78becc-ac73-4550-800f-6c2a9c34dde3" name="testproc" isExecutable="true" activiti:versionTag="2">

Comment: Otherwise - see section "6.3. Versioning of process definitions"